# How can I speed up the evaluation of a Dynamic Locator acting on a Region?

Tags: performance-tuning

I write this code

```
region = ParametricRegion[{Sin[u], 
   Sin[2*u]}, {{u, 0, 2*Pi}}]; DynamicModule[{p = {0, 0}}, 
 Show[ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2*u]}, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   PlotLabel -> Dynamic[p]], 
  Graphics[Locator[
    Dynamic[p, 
     If[RegionDistance[region, #1] < 0.2, 
       p = RegionNearest[region, #1]] &]]]]]
```

[image]

But the efficiency is very poor.

Comment: Could you not use TrackingFunction to achieve better performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### With `RegionNearest`

`RegionNearest` is a function that basically processes the region and returns a function of type `RegionNearestFunction` which is optimized for finding the nearest point in the region quickly. You should use the returned function to find the closest point in the region. As it is now you are recomputing this function again and again, which creates a lot of overhead. I might also suggest `LocatorPane` which has a background argument. This might allow for some further optimizations in which *Mathematica* does not have to redraw the background as much as it would have with the naive approach, although I don't know if this is the case. It also makes the syntax a bit simpler.

```
region = ParametricRegion[{Sin[u], Sin[2*u]}, {{u, 0, 2*Pi}}];
background = ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2*u]}, {u, 0, 2*Pi}];
nf = RegionNearest[region];

DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = nf[#]) &], background]
 ]
```

You can make `background` a function of `pt` if you wish to update the plot label. Another option would be to use `Column[{Dynamic[pt], LocatorPane[...]}]`.

### With `Nearest`

If you need something that is very, very fast and which you have more control over, you can try `Nearest` instead.

```
region = Table[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}];
background = ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}];
nf = Nearest[region];

DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = First@nf[#]) &], background]
 ]
```

The upside and the downside is that you have to decide how to sample the curve yourself.

Comment: That's great, much much faster.  Like you say, you can make `background` a function, or just use `Show[background , PlotLabel -> Dynamic[pt]]` in place of background.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bit faster.  First off, there's no reason to redraw the `ParametricPlot` every time you change `p`.  That sped it up a bit.  Then I figured, why make the `If` statement?  Let's just always set `p` equal to the nearest region point.  Getting rid of the `If` statement sped it up some more.

```
region = ParametricRegion[{Sin[u], Sin[2*u]}, {{u, 0, 2*Pi}}];
plot = ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2*u]}, {u, 0, 
   2*Pi}]; 
DynamicModule[{p = {0, 0}},
 Show[plot,
  Graphics[
   Locator[
    Dynamic[
     p,
     (p = RegionNearest[region, #1]; &)
     ]
    ]
   ]
  , PlotLabel -> Dynamic[p]]]
```

Comment: It's seem to be slightly slow too.

Comment: It's faster than your original version, but there's no question that Pickett's solution is the best.