# Point on the circle

Tags: graphics, manipulate, animation

How can I make a moving point on the circle with control?

```
Manipulate[
       ParametricPlot[Sqrt[50]{Cos[x],Sin[x]},{x,0,10Pi},
       Epilog->{PointSize[Large], Point[Table[{2,0}]]}, 
       PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,10}}],{{Sqrt[50],2,"Play"}, 1, 10}
]
```

Comment: Like my [before question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104393/how-can-i-speed-up-the-evaluation-of-a-dynamic-locator-acting-on-a-region)

Answer (score 3):

**Example:**

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Circle[],
   {Red, PointSize @ .05, Point@{Cos[x], Sin[x]}}
   }],
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}
 ]
```

Alternatively, if you would like to animate it:

```
Animate[
 Graphics[{
   Circle[],
   {Red, PointSize @ .05, Point@{Cos[x], Sin[x]}}
   }],
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}
 ]
```

**Output:**

[image: output example]

Comment: I'm extremly sorry, but can you give me the full code or explain where this part should be?

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome! There are two solutions (using `Manipulate` and using `Animate`), both visulize the same thing

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

```
Manipulate[ ParametricPlot[radius {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
    Axes -> True, Mesh -> {{{t, {Red, PointSize[.05]}}}}],
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {{radius, 2, "Play"}, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

**Original post:**

**Using `Clock` and  `ParametricPlot` with `MeshFunctions`**

```
Dynamic@ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Axes -> False, 
  Mesh -> {{{Clock[{0, 2 Pi}], {Red, PointSize[.05]}}}}]
```

**Using `Clock` and `ParametricPlot` with `Epilog`**

```
Dynamic@ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[.05], Red, With[{c = Clock[{0, 2 Pi}]}, Point[{Sin[c], Cos[c]}]]}]
```

both give

[image]

**Using `Animate`:** Both `MeshFunctions` and `Epilog` methods above can be used with `Animate` or `Manipulate`:

```
Animate[ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[.05], Red, Point[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}]}], {t, 0, 
   2 Pi}]

Animate[ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Axes -> False, 
  Mesh -> {{{t, {Red, PointSize[.05]}}}}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(To get the `Manipulate` version just change `Animate` to `Manipulate`)

Comment: Thank you. But I need that code has a scale and the part of the circle moves({{Sqrt[50],2,"Play"}, 1, 10}). Can you hepl me with it?

Comment: @MIla, please see the update. By the way, `Sqrt[50` is an unusal choice for a `Manipulate` variablename; to my surprise it works. I replaced it with `radius`.